# Import.io to extract data from URL with json

Tags: json, import.io

This is an example of the URL, there are multiple I want to extract.
http://www.walgreens.com/svc/products/search/?requestType=loyalty

How can I train the extractor to put the json in rows and columns? I can only get it to highlight the entire data and import.io puts it all on one row.

I want to use the URL with json as the full web page is loaded with javascript and doesn't train properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to do this. Which ones are you actually looking to scrape? However, it seems that the data are on several different json objects. *i.e. products, refinements, etc.*

So if you're going to scrape everything, you'd need to create different extractors for the different json objects. But there might be a better way.